# I'm having trouble setting up a jpanel and frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm pretty new to swing and am having some troubles.
Heres my code. I'm getting the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself
>       at java.awt.Container.checkAddToSelf(Container.java:472)
>       at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1083)
>       at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:410)
>       at UMSL.Eval.createUserInterface(Eval.java:126)
>       at UMSL.Eval.(Eval.java:95)
>       at UMSL.Eval.main(Eval.java:56)
>   Java Result: 1

Can anyone explain to me what this error message is trying to tell me and how I can make things work.

```
  private void createUserInterface()
{


  JPanel contentPane;

   contentPane = new JPanel();



JPanel instructorPanel = new JPanel();
instructorPanel.setBounds(40, 20, 276, 48);
instructorPanel.setBorder (BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder() );
instructorPanel.setLayout( null) ;
instructorPanel = new JPanel();
contentPane.add(instructorPanel);
  // set up Instructor Label
JLabel instructorLabel = new JLabel();
instructorLabel.setBounds (25, 15, 100, 20);
instructorLabel.setText("Instructor:");
instructorLabel.add (instructorLabel);
```

Comment: You're adding a label to itself. Add it to `instructorPanel`

Comment: `instructorPanel.setBounds(40, 20, 276, 48);`  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Reimeus said, you're trying to add a label to itself with the line
`instructorLabel.add (instructorLabel);`
I'm assuming that you're trying to add the label to the instructor panel which would be
`instructorPanel.add(instructorLabel);`

Comment: @user2980790 So you're not getting the error but the label still isn't showing?

Comment: @user2980790 Maybe time for a new question with your updated code